# Spring Batch 5 with two schemas : Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, entitymanagerfactory

I have the following problem that is preventing me from launching the batch correctly:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting
> constructor argument

Here's the main class:

```java
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager")
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBatchApplicationDemo {
    
     @Value("classpath:schema-postgresql.sql")
     private Resource schemaScript;
     
     @Value("schema-drop-postgresql.sql")
     private Resource dropSchemaScript;

     @Bean
        public DataSource batchDataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database?currentSchema=batchmetadata");
            dataSourceBuilder.username("postgres");
            dataSourceBuilder.password("password");
            
            DataSource dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.build();
            DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), dataSource);
            return dataSource;
        }
     
      private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
            final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
            populator.addScript(dropSchemaScript);
            populator.addScript(schemaScript);
            return populator;
        }

     @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database?currentSchema=schema_name");
            dataSourceBuilder.username("postgres");
            dataSourceBuilder.password("password");
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();   
        }

     
    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(batchDataSource);
    }


    public static void main(String e []) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBatchApplicationDemo.class);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(context.getBean(Job.class), jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Job Exit Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

   
    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, @Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
          return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                  .start(step(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                  .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
        String sql = "select * from person";
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .sql(sql)
                .beanRowMapper(Person.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name")
                .build();
    }

  @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, @Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
          return new StepBuilder("step-persons", jobRepository)
                  .<Person, Person>chunk(5, transactionManager)
                  .reader(itemReader())
                  .writer(itemWriter())
                  .build();
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

`application.properties`:

```ini
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=batchmetadata
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=batchmetadata
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

In essence, I want to have two schemas:

`batchmetadata`: Where I store batch metadata.
`schema_name`: Where I store data coming from a CSV file into the person table.